# How can I get my laptop's hardware configuration?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, configuration

I would like to to see all parts of my Dell laptop, especially my wireless card (but including other information other like CPU and GPU).

I tried some commands in the terminal as root but I didn't get useful results ....

Does anyone know the right commands or right program to do this?

I use Ubuntu 12.04, and I haven't installed any updates or installed additional drivers.

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for.. but a few commands based upon the details you provided would be: ifconfig, xinput -list, but what exactly are you trying to do/determine?  This is very open-ended, and should possibly be revised

Comment: Please edit your post to include some of the commands that you have tried. `lspci` will give you a general sense of hardware installed. `ifconfig` will show your network connections; `iwconfig` will give your wireless information.  Dash->Applications->Details will give the basic system and OS information.

Comment: You can type `sudo lshw > ~/systemdetails.txt` into a terminal, and read the systemdetails.txt in your preferred editor later.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Hardware Info.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

Once done, type

```
sudo hardinfo
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### I-Nex: Tool To List Hardware Information In Linux

I-Nex is an application that gathers information for hardware components available on your system and displays it using an user interface similar to the popular Windows tool CPU-Z.

**Install I-Nex in Ubuntu**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i-nex-development-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i-nex
```

**CPU**

[image]

**GPU**

Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller  NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]

Detected Both Intel & Nvidia

[image]

**Mobo**

[image]

**Sound**

Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k3.8.0-19-generic.

[image]

**Drives**

[image]

**Kernel** & **Modules**

[image]

**Select Modules**

[image]

**Web**

[image]

[image]

#### [For More Help](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/i-nex-tool-to-list-hardware-information.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the command line, try `sudo lshw` and/or `sudo dmidecode` and/or `sudo hwinfo`.  You may have to install these, depending on the state of your system.  These will give you what is probably too much information, but can include things like serial numbers and vendor model numbers, as well as other hardware and interfaces.  (I've looked up Dell service tags this way.)

Graphical programs in the repositories include sysinfo and hardinfo.